# Google Sheets, Conditional Formatting by Percentage Categories

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm looking to create some conditional formatting based upon a set of three percentage categories (please see [the following sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12CmHVyW8EbxqCX5PCZRio0MB3juXQoLP5oYzZ8VZU_o/edit?usp=sharing)), where a color is applied to multiple cells, but not all in a row:

1. 90% - 100%: Green
2. 50% - 89%: Yellow
3. 0% - 49%: Red

I'm able to get the percentages to change color based upon their content, but so far I've not been able to apply this change to the other cells. Is there a conditional formatting custom formula that I can use to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For range F3:H26 make 2 rulus with 'your formula':

1. `=$F3>=0.9` -- green
2. `=$F3>=0.5` -- yellow

and paint the range in red.

That's it!

[Look at example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v1wJtyEr5mHWT9vxzOJBOUNcJjCfp9y3zkjia2FNq7w/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3):

- Select all the cells that you want the rule to apply to
- Go to: Format > conditional formatting then in the tool bar on the right, click add new rule
- By format cell if section select "is between" and enter the criteria. Hit done
- Now click add new rule below the first one and repeat as above

this should work

Comment: This will only work for the cell with the percentage in it. The rest won't have a percentage, so as a result, the formatting won't apply.

Comment: I've just tested this and this definitely doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry try this select your range and enter by custom formula `=and($F3>0,$F3<1)` let me know if it worked and i'll edit the answer

Comment: @TooManyJulians Did you try the formula i mentioned in the previews comment?

Comment: I tried an alternate option and figured it out that way. thanks for trying though!

Answer (score 2):

When putting in conditional formatting with cell that has a percentage value in it you need to give ranges in the range of 0 to 1. In other word to set a format for range between 10% and 40% you would select "Is Between" and for values put in 0.1 and 0.4. This will apply formatting correctly. For percentages over 100% use 1.xx over 200% 2.xx etc...